# glTexSubImage3D throws GL_INVALID_ENUMERATION on NVIDIA

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm having problems when using the following statement on different GPUs:

```
glTexSubImage3D(target, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, layers, format, type, NULL);
```

on NVIDIA cards "format = GL_RGBA" throws a fatal error that causes the program to crash, but it works and throws no errors if I use the sized version "format = GL_RGBA8"

on AMD cards "format = GL_RGBA" works and throws no errors, "format = GL_RGBA8" also works, but throws the error "GL_INVALID_ENUMERATION"

--

I'm currently using GL_RGBA8, so it works on both cards, but I wonder if there is a way to do this that throws no errors on either card.

--

Here's the spec for glTexSubImage3D from Khronos.org

> format
>
> Specifies the format of the pixel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: GL_RED, GL_RG, GL_RGB, GL_BGR, GL_RGBA, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, and GL_STENCIL_INDEX.

--

I'm using opengl 4.3 core profile, glfw and glew. Here is my texStorage statement called before glTexSubImage3D

```
internalFormat = GL_RGBA8;
glTexStorage3D(target, 1, internalFormat, width, height, layers);
```

per the comments, the other values are

```
target = GL_TEXTURE_2D;
width = 4096;
height = 4096;
layers = 1;
format = GL_RGBA8;
type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
```

--

Am I using this incorrectly? Is there a way to satisfy both implementations?

Comment: Passing `NULL` to `TexSubImage` functions is not allowed. You need to fix that, regardless of the rest of your parameters.